# Disable the opening of submenu in jquery menu on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, submenu, jquery-ui-menu

I am using jquery menu in my application.I have 3 levels of submenu.
Like the one shown in the jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ankitap/WC3bE/

When we do mouse hover on the menu options,the submenu will open automatically.
I want to disable this feature and want to open the submenu only on click.
i tried to use:

```
$( "#menu a" ).menu({ role: null });
```

I have also tried to give level 1 class name as mainclass and level 2 class name as subclass.

```
      <script>
      $("#menu").menu();
      $("#menu a").click(function() {
      console.log($(this).text()); // gets text contents of clicked li
      $(".subclass a").show();  
      });

      $("#menu a").click(function() {
      $(".subclass a").hide();
      });
      </script>
```

the html code for this is:

```
<ul id="menu" class="mainclass">
  <li><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Addyston</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
    <ul class="subclass">
      <li >
          <a href="#">Ada</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">ankita</a>              
              </li>
          </ul>    
      <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
    <ul class="subclass">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Delphi</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Delphi</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>
</ul>
```

I could not stop the opening of submenu on mouse hover.
I want the submenu to open only after click.Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no js/jquery guru but maybe unbind mouseenter and mouseleave events

```
$("#menu").menu(/*{
select: function( event, ui ) {
  var selection = ui.item.text();
  var  get=this.event;
  console.log(get);
}}*/);
$('#menu').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
$("#menu a").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

note the `$('#menu').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');` statement